# Getting the same name for HTMLInputCheckbox

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Super newbie question here. I'm trying to teach myself Web Forms, so I'm experimenting with the `runat="server"` attribute. So here's my code:

```
<p>
Number of items:
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_name_qty" value="25" runat="server" />25
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_name_qty" value="50" runat="server" />50
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_name_qty" value="75" runat="server" />75
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_name_qty" value="100" runat="server" />100
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_name_qty" value="Other" runat="server" />Other
</p>
```

And here's what gets generated:

```
<p>
Number of items:
<input name="ctl01" type="checkbox" value="25" />25
<input name="ctl02" type="checkbox" value="50" />50
<input name="ctl03" type="checkbox" value="75" />75
<input name="ctl04" type="checkbox" value="100" />100
<input name="ctl05" type="checkbox" value="Other" />Other
```

So, it took my group of checkboxes that had the same name, and gave them separate names. Why is this? Even when I give them separate names (add an integer to the end of each one), they still get renamed.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get the checkboxes to output the same name? How can I even get the checkboxes to keep the names that I give them? I'd rather work with a name I give than "ctl01".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, that's [the default behaviour of asp.net.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) That is otherwise achieved with `<asp:CheckListBox />` control: [CheckListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)

```
  <asp:CheckBoxList id="checkboxlist1" 
       AutoPostBack="True"
       CellPadding="5"
       CellSpacing="5"
       RepeatColumns="2"
       RepeatDirection="Vertical"
       RepeatLayout="Flow"
       TextAlign="Right"
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="Check_Clicked"
       runat="server">

     <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>

  </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

That shows how to add items manually. You can also populate the check list from database

```
  System.Data.DataTable dtOptions = GetValuesFromDataBase();
  checkboxlist1.DataSource = dtOptions;
  checkboxlist1.DataBind();
```

**Update**

In Asp.Net 4 and above, you are given more control on [how control ID are generated (e.g. AutoID, Static, Predictable, Inherit)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Comment: Isn't this for Web server controls instead of HTML Server controls though? Up to this point I've shied away from the former because I'm a bit of a control freak with how my source code looks...

Comment: Asp.net would make your life simple if you don't fight it. There are several issues with it but you have to embrace them. If you want more control over your markup, look at ASP.Net MVC